# Best practises to verify card owner when adding credit card to user account

Tags: security, payment, credit-card

in our application we allow users to link card to their profile and use it later for payments inside our system. Recently we had a couple fraud attempts when users added stolen credit cards (so they knew all information about card, including CVV).
The only thing that we came up with is to make temporary payment of some small random amount so user can check bank transactions report and verify ownership by providing exact authorized amount.

Is there any other common proven ways to verify card ownership?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a couple of things you can do at the very least:

- Validating the house number and postcode/zipcode provided to you with the result returned to your from your payment processor on the pre-auth (AVS - Address Verification Service).
- 3D secure verification (Mastercard SecureCode or Verified by Visa) - the user is redirected to their issuer's site (or one ran for them by e.g. Arcot) and has to enter a secret only known to them.

Validating a small random amount is also a good check to make, however this takes a few days whereas the above can be validated instantly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, as I know 3D secure is not supported by all card issuers by default so it cannot be applied for all users?
We are using braintree, they provide AVS from the box, but seems that it is not so strong as transaction (fraudsters at our website knew addresses of stolen cards owners as well as other info)

Comment: You could check whether the issuer is enrolled, and if not you could do your random amount check.